# Trouble with core/session Messages

Tags: magento-1.9, template, session, core, messages

I'm worked on a new project with a own theme. Everything is fine, but any messages from modules, like the newsletter subscription, doesn't show in the frontend.

Take a look in the `SubscriberController.php` from the newsletter module - Method `newAction()`:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
...
$session->addSuccess($this->__('Confirmation request has been sent.'));
```

Nothing to see in the theme. A little test on top of the `page/1column.phtml` template:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Core Session test');
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess('Customer Session test');
```

Output (by `Mage_Cms_Block_Page`, because it is the homepage):

```
Customer Session test
```

In the `page/1column.phtml` template i called these childs:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

The `global_messages` leaves blank.

...

**Test 2**: I switch the theme to `default/modern`, add the testsnippets (`addSuccess(...)`) to 1column.phtml. Output:

```
Core Session test
Customer Session test
```

Have anybody an idea?

The final goal in my theme is, to set all messages in one of the root templates like 1column.phtml.

Thanks!

**Update:**
Tim's idea to remove all template files one by one return no effect. Next i checked if the core/session has the missing message. See my `1column.phtml`:

```
<?php

    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Core Session test');
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess('Customer Session test');

    $strHtmlLanguage = trim($this->getLang());
    $strBodyClasses = trim($this->getBodyClass());

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $strHtmlLanguage; ?>" lang="<?php echo $strHtmlLanguage; ?>" class="no-js">
<!-- 1column.phtml -->
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head'); ?>
</head>
<body class="<?php echo $strBodyClasses; ?>">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices'); ?>
    <div id="page-wrapper" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage">
        <link itemprop="publisher" href="organization" />
        <meta itemprop="inLanguage" content="<?php echo $strHtmlLanguage; ?>" />
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs'); ?>
        <main>
            <div id="page-content" role="main" itemprop="mainContentOfPage">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <?php var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true)); ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_html_blocks_body_end'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The dump output shows:

```
object(Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection)#230 (2) {
  ["_messages":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["success"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(Mage_Core_Model_Message_Success)#300 (6) {
        ["_type":protected]=>
        string(7) "success"
        ["_code":protected]=>
        string(17) "Core Session test"
        ["_class":protected]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["_method":protected]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["_identifier":protected]=>
        NULL
        ["_isSticky":protected]=>
        bool(false)
      }
    }
  }
  ["_lastAddedMessage":protected]=>
  object(Mage_Core_Model_Message_Success)#300 (6) {
    ["_type":protected]=>
    string(7) "success"
    ["_code":protected]=>
    string(17) "Core Session test"
    ["_class":protected]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["_method":protected]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["_identifier":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["_isSticky":protected]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Anything in logs?

Comment: hi tim! absolutly nothing. totally clean logs. i know that is a problem in the theme. but: where to find?

Comment: Te easiest thing to do is to remove files from your theme one by one. At some point you will see global messages which will point you on a problematic file.

Comment: i was afraid you'd say that... easy is relative :-) i will try it